# Segmentation violation with golang channels

Tags: go, channel

The below code opens 10,000 go routines, which make HTTP calls, get the response, close the response, and write to a channel with an ID.

In the second for loop, it prints out from that buffered channel the ID of the previous go routine.

This causes a segmentation violation, and I can't figure out why.

Panic:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x2293]
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    requests := 10000
    ch := make(chan string, requests)
    for i := 1; i <= requests; i++ {
        go func(iter int) {
            fmt.Println(iter)
            resp, _ := http.Get("http://localhost:8080/api/project")
            resp.Body.Close()
            ch <- fmt.Sprint("%i", iter)
        }(i)
    }
    for i := 1; i <= requests; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }
}
```

Comment: always, check, errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not check for any error when calling the api. Thus the error when trying to close a response that never arrived.

This code does not panic:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    requests := 10000
    ch := make(chan string, requests)
    for i := 1; i <= requests; i++ {
        go func(iter int) {
            fmt.Println(iter)
            resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8080/api/project")
            if (err == nil) {
              resp.Body.Close()
            }
            ch <- fmt.Sprint(iter)
        }(i)
    }
    for i := 1; i <= requests; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The general cause of this error is when you try to reference an object that does not exist or has not yet been created.

In the code above, if you try to call `resp.Body.Close()` when `body` does not exist, that becomes a nil pointer reference and hence the error.